# Arduino ESP8266 download big files from webserver

Tags: file, download, arduino, webserver, esp8266

I'm trying to read a big file on SD card and send it to client that's connected to web server. For server I'm using ESP8266WebServer.h

So far the only option that worked for me is this:

```
httpServer.sendHeader("Content-Type", "text/text");
httpServer.sendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"download.txt\"");
httpServer.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
File download = SD.open("test.txt");
String buffer = download.readString();
httpServer.send(200, "text/text", buffer);
download.close();
```

This isn't usable for me because the file would not fit into the stack. Is there a way to continuously send data to client? I've tried httpServer.sendContent(), but the sent data only shows as a webpage content and send() closes connection after the first data send.

EDIT:

Solution found in examples

```
httpServer.streamFile(download, "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: Did you check the [examples](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/SDWebServer/SDWebServer.ino)?

Comment: @gre_gor Thank you! I completely forgot about examples